# soft SVM - degenerate case

Tags: machine-learning, svm, libsvm

According to "[A Note on Support Vector Machine Degeneracy](https://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/7291/AIM-1661.pdf?sequence=2)", Theorem 4, if the dual problem for soft-SVM has a solution with $\alpha_i \in \{0,C\}, \forall i$, then $w=0$ for the primal problem.

In "[Uniqueness of the SVM solution](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/c8b8/16b48dcd4ea5b37c6bb9a238b44622eeacce.pdf)", there is an example which, I say, contradicts the theorem above:

Data: $x_1 = 1, y_1 = +1; x_2 = -1, y_2 = -1$

$C \in (0,1/2]$

Result: 
$\alpha_1 = \alpha_2 = C$

$w=2C \neq 0$.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Let's check if $w=2C$ is actually primal optimal...

The objective value when $w = 0$ would be $2C$.

When $w=2C$ the objective value would be $\frac{(2C)^2}{2} + (1+b-2C)+(1-b-2C) = 2C^2 - 4C + 2 = 2(C-1)^2$.

Then $w=0$ could be optimal when $C < (C-1)^2$ which happens for $C < \frac{3-\sqrt 5}{2} < \frac{1}{2}$, but not above it.

I'm not quite sure what to make of this - perhaps for this example, strong duality doesn't hold, invalidating both the example and the theorem.